# How do I include a 3rd party jar in maven?

Tags: java, maven, adobe-analytics

I have OmnitureAPI.jar and I could not find it in mvn repo. Hence I though I will include it myself using the following command that I found online describing a similar issue that I am currently facing.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=c:\kaptcha-{version}.jar -DgroupId=com.google.code -DartifactId=kaptcha -Dversion={version} -Dpackaging=jar
```

I have two questions:
1) Does the jar that I am including needs to following maven naming and packaging conventions such as the classes should be in src/main/java etc?
2) While executing above command what should I put in -DgroupId=xxxx and -DartifactId=xxx ?

Please guide

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/

Comment: If you are using netbeans you can "manually install." Another way is to set up an instance of artifactory, and add the jar there, then reference the artifactory in you settings.xml and you can add a pom dependcy to whatever you called the group and artifact in the artifactory repo.

Comment: also, if you are trying to include this jar in your build, and there are many developers who will need the jar, it is a good idea (IMO) to go the artifactory (or similar capability) route.

Comment: The problem is that this is not a maven convention following jar. How do I add this dependency now?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [Guide to installing 3rd party jars.](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)

If it's not a maven-built jar and there's no pom.xml, you'll need to specify these things yourself:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-your-jar> -DgroupId=<make-up-a-group-id> \
-DartifactId=<make-up-an-artifact-id> -Dversion=<specify-a-version> -Dpackaging=jar
```

The best way to do this is use the pom.xml file included in the jar, if it exists. I had to do this recently, and here's the command I used:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=./elasticsearch-river-jdbc-0.90.3.1.jar
```

If it can't find the POM, you may need to point mvn at the POM manually:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=elasticsearch-river-jdbc-0.90.3.1.jar -DpomFile=./META-INF/maven/org.xbib.elasticsearch.plugin/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/pom.xml
```

If there's no pom.xml in the jar, and no group id or artifact id exists, you can make up your own; but you need to then use the same parameters when you reference the JAR.

Comment: The jar is not a maven jar and hence there is no pom.xml, groupId or artifactId in the jar. How do I proceed?

Comment: I updated the answer. you need to specify the groupId, artifactId, and version, and you need to make them up yourself, essentially. When you include this in your maven project, you'll use those values to reference the lib.